# Recursive query in tree MySQL8 / MariaDB10

Tags: sql, recursion, mariadb

I have a tree-like structure for categories on my database:

```
create table cat(
     id int auto_increment primary key,
     url varchar(50),
     parent int references cat(id)
)
```

How can i build the URL of a category, by concatenating its url with the parent url? (until `parent` is not null)

I'm using MariaDB 10.2

Comment: Did you try recursive CTE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This recursive CTE will form a URL out of each level in the table, joining them with a `/` (although that is easily changed). The desired final node is specified in the CTE (in this example, it is `7`):

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE urls AS (
  SELECT url, parent
  FROM cat
  WHERE id = 7
  UNION ALL
  SELECT CONCAT_WS('/', cat.url, urls.url), cat.parent
  FROM urls
  JOIN cat ON cat.id = urls.parent
)
SELECT CONCAT('http://', url) AS url
FROM urls
WHERE parent IS NULL
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=e5c5e9acbeb49508792d93bb02472e0b)

You can get all of the available paths by omitting the `WHERE id =`  condition from the CTE. For my sample data, that gives:

```
url
http://home
http://home/apps
http://home/user
http://home/apps/excel
http://home/apps/word
http://home/user/nick
http://home/user/nick/docs
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=067bb98a44786cab7a9a414c57400eb9)

Comment: for real? that easy? it's almost 2 hours that i try trillion queries

Comment: I've written a few of these in my time... :)

Comment: Note I updated the query/demo to add a prefix to the URL as well. You can easily change all those string constants as necessary.